# Takes 1 positional argument but 2 error while python requests module

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I have the following test code

```
import requests 
import json

r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user')
print(r.status_code)
```

This is getting the following error, I reinstalled requests and urllib3 modules but didn't help

```
File "/data//temp/scratchprojects/data structures/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user')  
File "/data/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)  
  File "/data/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)  
  File "/data/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request  
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)  
  File "/data/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)  
  File "/data/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 412, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)  
  File "/data/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 315, in get_connection
    conn = self.poolmanager.connection_from_url(url)  
  File "/data/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 298, in connection_from_url
    return self.connection_from_host(  
  File "/data/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 245, in connection_from_host
    return self.connection_from_context(request_context)  
  File "/data/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 260, in connection_from_context
    return self.connection_from_pool_key(pool_key, request_context=request_context)  
  File "/data/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 281, in connection_from_pool_key
    pool = self._new_pool(scheme, host, port, request_context=request_context)  
  File "/data/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 213, in _new_pool
    return pool_cls(host, port, **request_context)  
  File "/data/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 906, in __init__
    HTTPConnectionPool.__init__(  
  File "/data/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 197, in __init__
    self.pool = self.QueueCls(maxsize)  
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Works for me `Python 3.9.7` - `print(requests.get('https://api.github.com/user').status_code)` in the REPL

Answer (score 0):

looks like a corrupted library. After removing the virtual environment and recreating it fixed the issue